# How can I make the CSS work on my Java project?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to implement a CSS document into my Java project. I'm using JavaFX as my graphic interface.

My code is:

```
Scene escena = new Scene(grid, 500, 500);
escena.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("estilos.css").toString());
```

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null
```

If tried to change the CSS document name, and some changes in the `getStylesheets` call, but it says that I'm obtaining a null pointer exception.

Comment: As specified in the duplicate (assuming it is in `src/main/resources` of your project), use: `escena.getStylesheets().add("estilos.css")`.

Comment: Now it shows this error dic 01, 2023 1:33:46 P.�M. com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
ADVERTENCIA: Resource "estilos.css" not found.

Comment: Where exactly is the resource located? If it is for example in `src/main/resources/my/package/estilos.css`, you probably need to use `/my/package/estilos.css` or `my/package/estilos.css`.